# Styling a select dropdown menu so it looks the same in all browsers and operating systems

Tags: html, select, drop-down-menu, menu

Given the powers of jquery and 3rd party vendors, is it possible to create/style an html select dropdown menu on a form so it looks the same in IE, FF, Chrome and Safari on Windows and Mac OS?

Comment: Check out [Formalize](http://formalize.me/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but the way most people are doing it is to completely replace the dropdown when the page first runs:

An example plugin that does this: http://gregfranko.com/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/

As an additional note, I do not recommend replacing the browser standard select box. The browser select box is implemented on a per operating system basis and uses operating system settings to provide a commonly understood ui element. An example is the select box on ios operates in a way familiar to the touch-based operating system.

Comment: SelectBoxIt uses the native select box for mobile devices including IOS and Android, which means that you get the benefit of the mobile "wheel" interface, while still being able to style the default Select Box button.  SelectBoxIt also allows you to trigger the native Select Box on desktop devices using the **native** option.  I highly recommend it... especially since I made it =)

Comment: Greg Franko: I did notice that, and your plugin is awesome. IOS was just one example, each operating system has it's own way of implementing select boxes which are familiar to it's users. Mac, Windows, IOS and various mobile browsers. Try out your plugin on an Android device.

Comment: I totally get that each OS has their own way of presenting select boxes.  With a few solid select box plugins out there, dev's can now choose whether they want to use different implementations (the standard way) or use a plugin that provides a consistent experience across OS's.  It is an interesting debate.